# CloudWatch agent manipulate log record before sending to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm searching for an option in CloudWatch agent where you can manipulate the log record data before sending it to AWS.

For example I have following log record:

```
2019-06-24 08:02:55,767 INFO [api,,,] 4110 --- [restartedMain] c.t.t.s.Application : authentication email was send to bogus@mail.com
```

And I want to be able to do the following with the log record:

```
2019-06-24 08:02:55,767 INFO [api,,,] 4110 --- [restartedMain] c.t.t.s.Application : authentication email was send to c71a72a90fab96c4e59d3a5799cb06f7
```

Would be a useful use case for anonymization of sensitive data before sending it to AWS.

Can't seem to find any information about this:

- [CloudWatch Agent Configuration File: Logs Section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection)

Comment: Probably not possible. Have you seen anything that makes you think it is possible to manipulate the log record before sending?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No I was hoping that there was a workaround or that I missed something.